# Symfony2.4.0 formbuilder 2d array values

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I have an array like this.

```
array(
1 => array("United States","Antigua and Barbuda","Anguilla","American Samoa","Barbados","Bermuda","Bahamas","Canada","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Grenada","Guam","Jamaica","Saint Kitts and Nevis","Cayman Islands","Saint Lucia","Northern Mariana Islands","Montserrat","Puerto Rico","Sint Maarten (Dutch part)","Turks and Caicos Islands","Trinidad and Tobago","Saint Vincent and the Grenadines","Virgin Islands, U.S.","Virgin Islands, U.S.")
,7 => array("Russian Federation","Kazakhstan")
,20 => array("Egypt")
,27 => array("South Africa")
,30 => array("Greece")
,31 => array("Netherlands")
,32 => array("Belgium")
,33 => array("France")
,34 => array("Spain")
,36 => array("Hungary")
,39 => array("Italy")
,40 => array("China")
,41 => array("Switzerland")
,43 => array("Austria")
,44 => array("United Kingdom","Guernsey","Isle of Man","Jersey")
,45 => array("Denmark")
,46 => array("Sweden")
,47 => array("Norway","Svalbard and Jan Mayen")
,48 => array("Poland")
)
```

and I would like it such that the values in the html select element have a value that is the same as the parent key. Right now I'm using

```
$builder->add('callingCode', 'choice', array(
        'choices'   => $thatarray));
```

but that results in optgroups like this.

```
1
    United States
    Antigua and Barbuda
    Anguilla
    ...
7
    Russian Federation
    Kazakhstan
20
    Egypt
...
```

United States has a value of 0, Antigua and Barbuda has a value of 1, Anguilla has a value of 2, Russian Federation has a value of 0, etc. That is not what I want. United States, Antigua and Barbuda, and Anguilla should have a value of 1. Russian Federation, and Kazahkstan should have a value of 7, and Egypt should have a value of 20. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a single array with key values

```
$thatarray=array(
"1" => "United States"
"1" =>"Antigua and Barbuda",
"1" =>"Anguilla",
"1" =>"American Samoa",
"1" =>"Barbados",
"7" => "Russian Federation",
"7" =>"Kazakhstan",
"20" => "Egypt",
./*other  countries */
.
.
.
.
);

$builder->add('callingCode', 'choice', array('choices'   => $thatarray));
```

Comment: This doesn't work since there are multiple values for a key. In this case, only Barbados, Kazakhstan, and Egypt will be displayed.